# Continuously getting data from server in android

Tags: android, android-service

I am starting a service from my activity.This is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService();
    }
    // Method to start the service
    public void startService() {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService() {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service.class));
    }
```

How can I start services if any files are uploaded to server at any time?

Comment: Register service class in manifest.xml under tag service.

Comment: @K. Sopheak I  have done this: <service
            android:name=".Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

Comment: have you read this thoroughly? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @user1506104 7  I have used alram manager.Is it correct way?

Comment: You should use socket programming. Check this [example](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

Comment: Build IntentService